# MySQL2 Gem Acces Denied but Login via Terminal Works

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I'm running a rake task and attempting to create a database connection to mysql via the mysql2 gem but for some reason I am getting this error:

```
*** Mysql2::Error Exception: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This is the connection code:

```
Mysql2::Client.new(host: server, database: db, username: user, password: pwd)
```

There are two reasons this is strange:

- I am able to use the same credentials to login via the terminal
- I created a VM (centos 7) and added a mysql database and uploaded the dump.sql file and was able to login just fine via the terminal and by using the MySQL2 gem. So I know that code works, I'm just not sure why it doesn't work for the mysql instance it is running on.

I've checked the user privileges and my user has all the necessary privileges, the database is running on localhost, I've tried setting the `host` parameter to `127.0.0.1` and got the same error.

Calling this: `mysql> select USER(), CURRENT_USER();` returns the following:

```
+--------------------+----------------+
| USER()             | CURRENT_USER() |
+--------------------+----------------+
| user@localhost     | user@%         |
+--------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Calling this:

```
mysql> Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(host,':',1) as 'ip'   From information_schema.processlist   WHERE ID=connection_id();
```

returns:

```
+-----------+
| ip        |
+-----------+
| localhost |
+-----------+
```

My MySQL version is 5.7.17 for linux, running on CentOS 7.

Any ideas why this wouldn't work for one Centos/MySql version and it would for another and why I can login though the terminal and can't in my code?

Comment: try `Mysql2::Client.new(:username => ENV['Opendata_DATABASE_USERNAME'], :password => ENV['Opendata_DATABASE_PASSWORD'], :host => ENV['Opendata_DATABASE_HOST'], :port => ENV['Opendata_DATABASE_PORT'], :database => ENV['Opendata_DATABASE_NAME'])` to add port?

Comment: If still fail, you can use root to connect by Mysql2::Client first, check if the user  permission problem?

Comment: No, adding the port didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Login via the terminal reset a new password, and it must can connect by new password via the mysql2 gem